# Swift framework successfully built, import into project successfully compiled, but no access to any public class

Tags: swift, frameworks, swift2

[image: Framework Successfully Built]
[image: Project Successfully Compiled]
[image: Error After Project Successfully Compiled]
[image: Build Settings]
First, if framework has problem, framework shouldn't been built successfully.
Second, if something wrong with importing framework or setting, project shouldn't been complied successfully.

and here is the swift header, `GestureKit-Swift.h`

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 2.0 (swiftlang-700.0.42.3 clang-700.0.53.3)
#pragma clang diagnostic push

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
# include <uchar.h>
#elif !defined(__cplusplus) || __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
#endif

typedef struct _NSZone NSZone;

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif

#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted) 
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
#endif
typedef float swift_float2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef float swift_float3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef float swift_float4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef double swift_double2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef double swift_double3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef double swift_double4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
typedef int swift_int2  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(2)));
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
@class GKPattern;
@class GKGesture;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10GestureKit12GKClassifier")
@interface GKClassifier : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray<GKPattern *> * __nonnull patterns;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray * __nonnull minPeakHeight;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) double minProminence;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger peakHalfWidth;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger window;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger length;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger width;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithPatterns:(NSArray<GKPattern *> * __nonnull)patterns minPeakHeight:(NSArray * __nonnull)minPeakHeight minProminence:(double)minProminence peakHalfWidth:(NSInteger)peakHalfWidth window:(NSInteger)window OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (GKGesture * __nullable)classify:(GKPattern * __nonnull)testCase;
@end

@class NSNotification;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10GestureKit9GKGesture")
@interface GKGesture : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * __nonnull name;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * __nonnull notificationName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNotification * __nonnull notification;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithName:(NSString * __nonnull)name OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)registerNotification:(id __nonnull)observer selector:(SEL __null_unspecified)selector;
- (void)deregisterNotification:(id __nonnull)observer;
- (void)postNotification;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10GestureKit9GKPattern")
@interface GKPattern : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * __nonnull name;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSArray *> * __nonnull data;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger length;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger width;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithData:(NSArray<NSArray *> * __nonnull)data OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithName:(NSString * __nonnull)name data:(NSArray<NSArray *> * __nonnull)data OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (BOOL)isAlignedWith:(GKPattern * __nonnull)rhs;
- (void)saveLocally;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10GestureKit7GKQueue")
@interface GKQueue : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSArray *> * __nonnull data;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger length;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger width;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL full;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithLength:(NSInteger)length width:(NSInteger)width OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (GKPattern * __nullable)enque:(NSArray * __nonnull)data;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10GestureKit10GKRecorder")
@interface GKRecorder : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSArray *> * __nonnull data;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger length;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger width;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithWidth:(NSInteger)width OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)enque:(NSArray * __nonnull)data;
- (GKPattern * __nonnull)createPattern:(NSString * __nonnull)name;
- (void)reset;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10GestureKit11GKUtilities")
@interface GKUtilities : NSObject
+ (double)findCost:(GKPattern * __nonnull)lhs rhs:(GKPattern * __nonnull)rhs searchRange:(NSInteger)searchRange;
+ (double)findDistance:(GKPattern * __nonnull)lhs rhs:(GKPattern * __nonnull)rhs lhsIndex:(NSInteger)lhsIndex rhsIndex:(NSInteger)rhsIndex;
+ (NSArray<NSArray *> * __nonnull)initCostTable:(NSInteger)length;
+ (NSArray * __nonnull)quantize:(NSArray * __nonnull)data;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```